# My script is not working, sorry I know this might be repetitive but I am still getting used to perl

Tags: linux, perl

When I try to run my script I get the error message uninitialized value $file at line 38 and the real trouble maker is readline() on closed filehandle IN at line 40. My code is below for reference and thanks for reading if you did!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $name = 'P2A.pl';
my $version = 'alpha';

my $usage = <<"OPTIONS";

NAME            $name
VERSION         $version

SYNOPSIS        This script would calculate the number of individual sequences
                per multifasta file

COMMAND         P2A.pl -fa *.fasta -out output.txt

-fa (--fasta)   FASTA input files
-out (--output) Desired output file name [Default: output.txt]

OPTIONS

die "$usage" unless @ARGV;

my $file;
my @fasta;
my $output = 'output.txt';
GetOptions(
    'fa|fasta=s@{1,}' => \@fasta,
        'out|output=s'  => \$output
);

open OUT, ">", "$output";

while (my $fasta = shift@fasta){
        open IN, "<", "$file";
        my $sequence = 0; ## Keeping a counter
        while (my $line = <IN>){
                ## Looking for FASTA header
                if ($line =~ m/^>/){
                        $sequence++;
                }
        }
    print OUT "$fasta\t$sequence\n";
}
```

Comment: How do you expect `$file` to get set?

Comment: Changing `open IN, "<", "$file";` to `open IN, "<", "$fasta";` might help. Generally using `open ... or die` is a recommended approach, see https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: To support certain strange chars in file names I think `"$output"` and `"$fasta"` should be just `$output` and `$fasta` in your two `open` lines. Also `while(my $fasta = shift@fasta)` could be changed to `for my $fasta (@fasta)`.  Also, you don't need the `m` in `m/^>/`.

Comment: @KjetilS. I agree that the quotes are not needed, but what's a scenario in which they might cause a problem?

Comment: My issue with the quotes might only be relevant for the two arguments mode of `open`. Not sure. In `open IN, "$filename"` otherwise valid filename chars like `|`, `<`, `;` wouldn't be, at least not everywhere in the filename.